# Excel Office Fluent Ribbon - Populate ComboBox OnLoad

Tags: excel, controls, ribbon, fluent

I'm developing a custom Ribbon for an Excel workbook. I currently have ActiveX objects in a sheet, such as a combobox. In ThisWorkbook, I execute code to populate the combobox. I'm working to transition away from sheet objects, and instead use objects in the custom Ribbon.

When the workbook is loaded, is it possible to push the list contents to the Ribbon combobox and refresh (invalidate) the ribbon to show the results? if so, it would be helpful to see an example of doing so.

If someone needs to see specific code, I can update accordingly. Thanks

**Update - Narrowing down the issue**

Following the guides I've found, I can get a callback to fire OnLoad, now I'd like to understand how to get the query results to populate the list. I have query results, but when I assign them to returnedVal, it just doesn't work (no error). Here are my callbacks:

```
'Callback for SWcboFilterList getItemLabel
Public Sub SWcboFilterList_getItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, index As 
Integer, ByRef returnedVal)

Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "SELECT [PGROUP] FROM [tblProperties] GROUP BY [PGROUP] HAVING ((([P_GROUP]) Is Not Null));"

adoQuery sSQL

returnedVal = myResults.GetRows

myResults.Close
End Sub
```

and

```
'Callback for SWcboFilterList getItemCount
Public Sub SWcboFilterList_getItemCount(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef 
returnedVal)

Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "SELECT [PGROUP] FROM [tblProperties] GROUP BY [PGROUP] HAVING ((([P_GROUP]) Is Not Null));"

adoQuery sSQL
returnedVal = myResults.RecordCount

myResults.Close
End Sub
```

If I set returnedVal to "Test" and 1 respectively, it works. So how must the data be formatted to get the Dropdown in the ribbon to accept it?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a link that seems to have all the elements: https://exceloffthegrid.com/inserting-a-dynamic-drop-down-in-ribbon/

Comment: This looks like a good source, but it doesn't appear to show how the list is populated on Load. The onload code only sets a ribbon variable. Do you have to execute a callback within the onload sub? They all appear to be 'get' based, as in obtaining data from the list, rather than pushing data to it.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I think maybe that is the way the elements are displayed, and that it all happens as the combobox is shown and clicked, not at ON_LOAD. If it was me, I'd try that code and work from there. You'll have a much more specific question to ask here then.

Comment: Did you get this working. I'm having a similar issue where I cannot get the `getLabel` and `getLabelID` callbacks to fire no matter how many times I invalidate the ribbon or the control...

Comment: Is this really about the Fluent Ribbon (https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon) ?

Comment: Excel Office fluent ribbon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon using customUI XML